# Is there any way to connect to my WinXP computer remotely using RDC when its disabled in settings?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, remote-desktop, group-policy, regedit

I forgot to enable the checkbox "Allow Users to connect remotely to this computer" in "My computer" properties of my work computer. (WinXP SP3). Now I need to RDC (mstsc) to this computer from a remote location (outside) and I am in a different city on a business trip.
[image]

Also there are no VNC or similar server setup on that machine.

I am able to access the system in windows network (*\\hostname*, using VPN) & I think that's the only access I have. My username account type is Admin.

One option I tried is - [Connect Network Registry](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/regedit_connect_network_registry.mspx) of that system in regedit so that I can set the RDC checkbox from registry 
(*HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\DenyTSConnections* - although I not sure if this is the exact path of that checkbox). 
  But I am getting an error, you do not have required privileges.

**Is there something I can do to get a Remote Connection to that computer? Please suggest.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No answers yet, anyways thanks all..

I was able to get around this issue using [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and [REG](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/reg.mspx)

```
-> "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" DWORD fDenyTSConnections
```

Answer (score 0):

open cmd window

> reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal
>   Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

Comment: Added complete options to enable remote desktop.